# Give focus to a control but scroll to different one

Tags: asp.net

After a postback, I want my page to have focus on a child control of a gridview, but scroll the page to a different part.
the standard myGridView.Focus(), called on the Page_Load or Page_prerender, insert a

```
WebForm_AutoFocus('myGridViewClientID');
```

in the rendered html.
This function move also the scroll not to the required position

Any suggestion?

my try: use some function injected by Asp.NET:

```
function FocusWithoutScroll(focusId) {
    var targetControl;
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        targetControl = document.getElementById(focusId);
    }
    else {
        targetControl = document.all[focusId];
    }
    var focused = targetControl;
    if (targetControl && (!WebForm_CanFocus(targetControl))) {
        focused = WebForm_FindFirstFocusableChild(targetControl);
    }
    if (focused) {
        try {
            focused.focus();
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }
}
```

but in order to use this code, I have to include some .axd resource files: it seems ASP.NET automatically include them when you set 
    someControl.Focus();
in your server side code. but this in turn insert the 
    WebForm_AutoFocus('myGridViewClientID');

which scroll the page to the wrong position

Answer (score 1):

There's a client-side method [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) that scrolls page till the element is visible. You can issue server-side command:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript","document.getElementById('SecondElementID').scrollIntoView();", true);
```

Where 'SecondElementID' is id of the element you want to scroll to.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v8455c79/** this demo shows how focus can be set on one element and page scrolled to another

Comment: This lead to some blinking: the page first scrolls where  WebForm_AutoFocus('myGridViewClientID')
want it to scroll, then move back to the desired position.

Comment: Then don't use `myGridView.Focus()` do something like `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript1","document.getElementById('myGridViewClientID').focus();", true);` instead - this will cause just focus, but not autoscroll

Comment: the gridview itself cannot have focus: ASP.net Javascript use a fancy 

    WebForm_FindFirstFocusableChild

to find the focusable children within the grid

Comment: Then you can do it yourself - find element in question and use it in your custom focusing

Comment: That the road I was taking: I extracted my FocusWithoutScroll from the Asp.NET, skipping the "scroll to control" part

But it seems that I have to rewrite to much code generated by Asp.NET.... I'm a noob in javascript, I hope I can recycle some good code written by Microsoft or some expert...